# how to query today in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, activeandroid

I have a local database in android using sqlite , i used active android and my table pojo is like this:

```
@Column(index = true, unique = true , onUniqueConflict = Column.ConflictAction.REPLACE)
public long taskId;
@Column( index = true)
public String taskIdno;
@Column()
public String taskDescription;
@Column()
public String taskTypeId;
@Column()
public String customerName;
@Column()
public String customerContact;
@Column()
public String address;
@Column(index = true)
public int status;
@Column()
public Date startSchedule;
@Column()
public int first_visit;
@Column()
public String coordinates;
@Column()
public int radius;
@Column()
public long location_type_id;
@Column()
public long duration;
@Column()
public long taskType_id;
```

My problem is that my query for today doesnt work, Or there is something im missing here.

```
  public static List<AATask> allTaskOrderedByDate(String asc_desc){
        From from = new Select().from(AATask.class).where("strftime('%Y-%m-%d', startSchedule ) = strftime('%Y-%m-%d' , DATE('now'))").orderBy("startSchedule ".concat(asc_desc));
        Log.w(TAG , from.toSql());
        return from.execute();
    }
```

startSchedule is converted to timeInMilliseconds(correct me if im wrong) default to active android Date object, How do I get today query?

Answer (score 3):

If you are storing your date as INTEGER, try this:

```
select * from my_table where date(dateColumn) = date('now');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be like this :

```
select * from <table> where <date_col> = current_date
```

SQLite allows selecting current date, time and timestamp like this :

```
select current_date, current_timestamp, current_time from <table>
```

The output of above query will be like this :

```
"2015-11-04","2015-11-04 04:08:47","04:08:47"
```

If you are storing date as integer or unix epoch then do the following :
1. Get the current time in milliseconds in JAVA. Lets say it is current_time_in_mill

Then use the following query

```
select date(current_time_in_mill, 'unixepoch') from <table>;
```

Example try this : `select date(1092941466, 'unixepoch')`

Comment: the time used in my sqlite is INTEGER, I dont think that this answers my problem. It seems to me my problem is related to conversion of date now in sqlite to system current time millis.

Comment: Key question is : What are you saving in table ? Are you saving as integers / milliseconds / epoch time ? - If yes, then see my new query 3 

If you are saving date as YYYY-MM-DD which is default format in SQLite then the above queries will work.

Comment: active android automatically saves Object Date to milliseconds. As what my Table Pojo stands. So it is in Milliseconds.

Comment: yes i would really love to try that example, but could you help me with something like turning yyyy-mm-dd and remove HH:mm:ss to milliseconds so that i could get the today query?

Comment: is this correct? strftime('%Y-%m-%d', datetime(startSchedule , 'unixepoch') ) = strftime('%Y-%m-%d' , DATE('now' , 'unixepoch'))