# How To Fetch Data According to Date in Sqlite Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

In my database table, I have a Date column and 2 other columns.
I want to write a query which retrieves the data which has been saved `today`, according to the system date.I tried many query but it does'nt work..
Please help any help Appreciated

Thanks in Advance :)

```html
public class UserDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    
        public static final String DATABASENAME = "DATABASENAME2";
        public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
        
        public UserDbHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context,DATABASENAME,null,DB_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BluetoothDevice ( Device VARCHAR , Address VARCHAR , Date VARCHAR);");
        
        }
        public List<BluetoothDevice>  getItemFromDatabase(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
            List<BluetoothDevice> result = new ArrayList<>();
            // query database elements
            Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("Select * from BluetoothDevice;", null);
        
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                Date v = new Date();
                v.setTime(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Date")) * 1000);
                Date date = new Date();
                date.setTime(Long.valueOf(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Date"))));
                result.add(
                        new BluetoothDevice(
                                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Device")),
                                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Address")),
                                date
        
                        )
                );
            }
            c.close();
            return result;
        }
        
        public void store(List<BluetoothDevice> data,SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
            for (BluetoothDevice value : data) {
                String s = String.valueOf(new Date().getTime());
                //insert in database
                sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO  BluetoothDevice VALUES(?,?,?,?);", new String[]{value.name, value.address, s});
        
            }
        }
        
        
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: What is the question? If you **want** something, than please explain what you have tried to get that

Comment: And I think you want `c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex("Date"))`

Comment: i want to retrive data from database according to present date

Comment: some thing like Select * from BluetoothDevice where date = today date

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513353/how-to-query-today-in-sqlite

Answer (score 1):

First get instance of calendar. Then use it to get the time.

```
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Then use getmethod from calendar instance to get present time. And then use the database method mentioned below to replace your query and selection args.

```
get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY): 0 to 23
get(Calendar.MINUTE): 0 to 59
get(Calendar.SECOND): 0 to 59

public Cursor getInformation(SQLiteDatabase db,string date){
    Cursor cursor;
    String[] projections={NAME.OF.COLUMNS.YOU.WANT1, NAME.OF.COLUMNS.YOU.WANT2};
    String selection=COLUMN.NAME.OF.DATE+" LIKE ?"
    String[] selection_args={date};
    cursor=db.query(TABLE_NAME,projections,selection,selection_args,null,null,null);
    return cursor;
}
```

Comment: but i didnt made a separate column i made a column in a query

Comment: i posted my database class